# Is it possible to include a page for visitors while using devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

I am using the `devise` gem for authentication in my website.

I would like to include the home page to be able to be displayed for visitors (displaying a catalog of products and their average ratings) but am not sure how to do this.

Is this even possible? or will devise allow us to create an application where every single page would be displayed only if and only the user is logged in?

Comment: @Vasilisa - would you be able to help me with this please?

Comment: Did you place  before_action :authenticate_user! on ApplicationController to require authentication?

Comment: Am pretty sure I did it. If I remove that, would that solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `before_action :authenticate_user!`from ApplicationController and add it to single controllers for which you require authentication, leaving out those for which authentication is not required (and visitors can access).

Comment: I would not be able to try this for a couple of hours probably but will definitely try this today and get back. Thank you very much for your help!!